# ¿Son éstas las vocales IPA que se usan en español?

Tags: pronunciación, vocales

[En este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtGHv1a4b48) se muestra lo que parece ser las vocales a-e-i-o-u del español, pero tengo la duda si esas son en realidad las vocales usadas en español, y si los símbolos son los mismos dados a estas en el [cuadrilátero cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_vowels#Table_of_cardinal_vowels).

Comment: The first link is for the wikipedia too, so I don't know what video you mean, but yes, a-e-i-o-u are the vowels in spanish, the other symbols are used only for fonetics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sí, es correcto. Las vocales en español son cinco, tanto en la escritura [*] como en la pronunciación: dos cerradas (i,u) dos semiabiertas (e,o) y una abierta (a).

Y la ubicación en el mapa vocálico está bien, se corresponde a lo que puedes ver en [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology#Vowels):

[image]

Como curiosidad: el [japonés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Vowels) tiene, muy aproximadamente, (en la pronuniación, claro) las mismas vocales.

[*] Aunque la correspondencia no es totalmente uno a uno: la excepción es la "u" muda en los grupos "que-qui-gue-gui"

Comment: La "u" es muda en esos grupos, y para hacerla sonar con la "g" hay que agregarle dieresis a la u, como en el caso de "cigüeña".